# Remove \n or \t from a given string

Tags: python, string

How can I strip a string with all `\n` and `\t` in python other than using `strip()`?

I want to format a string like `"abc   \n \t \t\t \t \nefg"` to `"abcefg`"?

```
result = re.match("\n\t ", "abc \n\t efg")
print result
```

and result is `None`

Answer (score 26):

It looks like you also want to remove spaces. You can do something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abc \n \t \t\t \t \nefg"
>>> s = re.sub('\s+', '', s)
>>> s
'abcefg'
```

Another way would be to do,

```
>>> s = "abc \n \t \t\t \t \nefg"
>>> s = s.translate(None, '\t\n ')
>>> s
'abcefg'
```

Comment: Parameters for `translate()` changed in Python >3. It now takes a translation table which can be generated by `str.maketrans()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 14):

Some more non-regex approaches, for variety:

```
>>> s="abc \n \t \t\t \t \nefg"
>>> ''.join(s.split())
'abcefg'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if not c.isspace())
'abcefg'
```

Comment: This is significantly faster than re.

Comment: @seth: I think `translate` usually comes out the winner in these games, where it's applicable.  I just don't care for regexps. :^)

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
import re

s = 'abc \n \t \t\t \t \nefg'
re.sub(r'\s', '', s)
=> 'abcefg'
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for the most Pythonic way to do it

```
>>> text = 'abc\n\n\t\t\t123'
>>> translator = str.maketrans({chr(10): '', chr(9): ''})
>>> text.translate(translator)
'abc123'
```

You can use translator to change any character in a string into another you want

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather avoid REs.
Simply replace '\t' and '\n' by the blank character ''.

```
def clean_string(st: str) -> str:
    #  remove \n and \t
    st = st.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    return st


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expected = clean_string("abc   \n \t \t\t \t \nefg")
    print(f"{expected}") # equals to "abcefg"
```